How can I get the Store info with WIX rest API
I've implemented the Advanced Oauth flow with a WIX app and REST API using the docs: https://dev.wix.com/docs/rest/app-management/oauth-2/sample-flows
This gives me a valid access and refresh token.
I want to retrieve some basic store information, like the domain and shop name. I'm unable to find suitable documentation on the dev.wix.com domain for this issue. Could someone give me a hulpful suggestion?

You can find the domain and site display name under the Site Properties API: https://dev.wix.com/docs/rest/business-management/site-properties/properties/get-site-properties
Hope this helps! Good luck.
